# Running out of memory with ddply summarize

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe of repeated measures in long format (41764 observations).  I am trying to summarize the dataframe and make a new dataframe with a single value for each different individual (for a total of 3112 observations).  I am using ddply summarize, and more background on my particular case is at [New dataframe with difference between first and last values of repeated measurements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625792/new-dataframe-with-difference-between-first-and-last-values-of-repeated-measurem).

I am using this code

```
df2 <- ddply(df1, .(indv), summarize, df1['value1'], df1['value2'])
```

but when I run this, I get this error

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 991.6 Mb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In output[[var]][rng] <- df[[var]] :
Reached total allocation of 8088Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In output[[var]][rng] <- df[[var]] :
Reached total allocation of 8088Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In output[[var]][rng] <- df[[var]] :
Reached total allocation of 8088Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In output[[var]][rng] <- df[[var]] :
Reached total allocation of 8088Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

I am not sure how to work around this.  I've tried saving all memory-resident dataframes as files, closing R, and then importing these back into R.  This does seem to save memory at least initially, however I still run out of RAM when running the ddply summarize.

I have 8 gb of RAM on this machine, and all of this is available to R.  Does anyone know what I can do to address this problem?

Perhaps I should not be using ddply summarize, maybe there is a better way to do this?

EDIT:  It seems I may have been issuing the command incorrectly.  A command like

```
df2 <- ddply(df1, .(indv), summarize, value1=(tail(value1, 1)), value2=(tail(value2, 1)), group=(tail(group, 1)))
```

seems to give the result I am looking for.

Comment: What's the next step? You might not need to do this.

Comment: Hey LostBrit, thanks for your comment.  What I ultimately want to do is just calculate the mean and SEM of value1 and value2, for individuaols "indv" in different groups.  So, I'm basically just trying to take the last instance of value1 and value2 from my dataframe and make a new dataframe.  Maybe something like this is more like I need: df2 <- ddply(df1, .(indv), summarize, tail(value1, 1), tail(value2, 1), tail(group, 1))

Comment: plyr doesn't really handle large numbers of levels very well. You might be best served by doing it in base R.

Comment: Dear Hong, thanks for your comment.  I've never done this in base R.  Can you give me more info on how I could do this in base R?  Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a job for `aggregate()`, but without data it's hard to try anything out. I'm thinking `aggregate(cbind("value1.mean" = value1, "value2.mean" = value2)~indv,df1, mean)` might help.

Comment: LostBrit, can you see any problem with the solution I posted below?  Thanks!

Comment: Thomas, Please post your `sessionInfo()` as well (edit your original post, do ***not*** paste in comments). Can you link your data or is it confidential? I don't believe `plyr` has issues with handling large levels (or I hadn't faced any yet). I'd be willing to debug the issue (if any).

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks to the help of LostBrit, I've come to realize that I was issuing the wrong command (or maybe I wan't clear on what exactly I was trying to do in the first place).  It seems that this code gives the result I want:

```
df2 <- ddply(df1, .(indv), summarize, 
       value1=tail(value1, 1), 
       value2=tail(value2, 1), 
       group =tail(group, 1))
```

Thanks for the help everyone!